# Open a new window after button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to open a new window after a click event. It opens the same page but not the page that I passed as a URL parameter.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('Report.aspx','mywindow','menubar=1,resizable=1,width=900,height=600');", true);
```

Comment: check using your browser tools for javascript errors.

Comment: did you try to put whole address instead of Report.aspx? (like http://example.com/Report.aspx)

Comment: @Aristos there's no errors on the console

Comment: @HosseinBadrnezhad yes, i tried puttin the whole address Ex: ~/Report.aspx  (The page is on root)

Comment: I tried your code and it worked. but opened page in a pop up not a new tab.

Comment: I found the problem, it was a validation on the form that I was trying to open. It sends me back to the first page... My bad. thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use (Show) Bootstrap Modal Popup Window from Server Side (Code Behind) in ASP.Net, also check below example.

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Open-Show-Bootstrap-Modal-Popup-Window-from-Server-Side-Code-Behind-in-ASPNet.aspx

**OR**

Html

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:return ViewAndApprove('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name")%>','<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Email")%>')">
                                    Edit </a>
```

Javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
  eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
  if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
 }
 function ViewAndApprove(i,J)
    {
             window.open('Report.aspx?UserName='+i+'&UserEmail='+J,'RPO','scrollbars=yes,width=540,height=300;');
    }

 //-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was a validation on the form that I was trying to open. It sends me back to the first page... My bad. thanks for the answers